# how to correctly reset api state in rtk query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I'm facing a problem reseting api state in RTK

```
import  apiSlice from "apiSlice";
import logout  from "logout";

export const apiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (...) => ({
        url: "/",
        method: "POST",
        body: { ... },
      }),
    }),
    mlogout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/logout",
        method: "POST",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(logout());
          dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState());
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
    }),
    refresh: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/refresh",
        method: "GET",
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useMlogoutMutation, useRefreshMutation } =
  apiSlice;
```

the logout is a reducer action with a token set to null.

for some reason the api state keep one rtk query after logging out even with the resetApiState, isn't the rtk queries suppose to unsubscribe when unmounting? or should the resetApiState be delayed and for how long?

I tried  to delay the resetApiState using setTimeout

Comment: I just came across your question, so ignore if you've already resolved this. I'm not entirely sure about your question however, what is the query that is being kept after logging out? Is there data remaining in store state? The only code issue jumping out to me is that you named this component and your main apiSlice the same, they should have diff names, currently you'd be injecting endpoints into this component - see the example in the docs https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting